# Fixing data that contains numeric overflow

Tags: excel

I have been given a dataset that I have identified contains records with a numeric overflow eg -214012688. Is there a way for me to fix this?

Here's a sample of data I have

```
2142936357
2143000225
2142936544
2142974737
2142935734
2143051458
-2143303677
-2142887448
2142866111
2142864212
2143020049
2143009445
2143300604
2143121125
-2142802104
2142801451
```

The dataset is not sorted so the numbers aren't in order. when I asked my client why there's negative numbers its because it went over the max integer amount.

Comment: Needs sample data (more than just one number) and expected results (because we don't know what you mean by "fixing data").  What would you like to turn that number into?

Comment: I've added a sample of the data. the expected result should be higher than 2147483647 as the reason its negative is from going over that number in their data warehouse

Comment: So you just need the absolute value of the numbers so they show as positive? `=ABS(A1)` and copy down?

Comment: Well no I'll need a way to get the original number which is above 21247483647 as from what i understand about integers is it'll go -2147483648 if you add 1 to the max int.

Comment: In your sample data, none of the negatives are anywhere close to 2,147,483,647.  In fact, all of your negative numbers are in the same range as the positives, ~4 million smaller than your target number.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your values have become positive after rolling over, there is no way to fix it, but if that's not the case, you can write [a custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to get the absolute value of the difference between each negative value and the signed minimum, then add that to the signed maximum. Here is a JavaScript function for it:

```
function signedRolloverToUnsigned (x, signedMin, signedMax) {
  if (x < 0) {
    x = Math.abs((signedMin - 1) - x) + signedMax;
  }
  return x;
}
```

And here is the custom Google sheet function you'd need if you just want to copy + paste and use it in your document:

```
/**
 * Converts signed rollover (negative) values to their equivalent unsigned positive values
 *
 * @param {number} value The value to convert.
 * @return The unsigned representation of the input value.
 * @customfunction
 */
function signedRolloverToUnsigned (value) {
  if (value < 0) {
    value = Math.abs((-2147483648 - 1) - value) + 2147483647;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Here is a working example using the data you provided:

```js
'use strict';

function signedRolloverToUnsigned (x, signedMin, signedMax) {
  if (x < 0) {
    x = Math.abs((signedMin - 1) - x) + signedMax;
  }
  return x;
}

const text = `2142936357
2143000225
2142936544
2142974737
2142935734
2143051458
-2143303677
-2142887448
2142866111
2142864212
2143020049
2143009445
2143300604
2143121125
-2142802104
2142801451`;

const arrSource = text.split('\n').map((x) => {
  return parseInt(x);
});

const signedRange = [-2147483648, 2147483647];

const arrFixed = arrSource.map((x) => signedRolloverToUnsigned(x, signedRange[0], signedRange[1]));


//---Ignore: For displaying output --->

document.body.style = 'background-color: #eeeeee; padding: 1rem;';
const pre = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre'));
const samp = pre.appendChild(document.createElement('samp'));
samp.textContent = arrFixed.join('\n');
const styles = {
  'box-sizing': 'border-box',
  'background-color': 'white',
  'border-radius': '0.5rem',
  'display': 'block',
  'padding': '1rem',
};

for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(styles)) {
  samp.style.setProperty(prop, value);
}
```